# Display content type in custom display format

Tags: 7, users, entities

I created an content type of name "profile", where it has fields
**Profile Name**, **Image** , **message** , **body**.

It displays in this format attached image_1
[image: Default format of Drupal 7]

Now how can we arrange or make change in custom format like below image image_2
how can we displayed to end user

[image: custom made profile]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `node--NAMECONTENTTYPE.tpl.php` in your directory template. Please see this documentation and comments about templates in Drupal 6 http://drupal.org/node/17565, this will give you a guidance to recognize some few differences with Drupal 7.

to be more detailed, you can copy/paste to your theme directory the file node.tpl.php (located in `modules > node` or already located inside your theme directory) and rename it according your content type. for example, if the Content Type is `Article` the name will be `node--article.tpl.php`

already inside in `node--article.tpl.php` you can see the variable `$content` or you can use `$node`. `$content` (or `$node`) variable is carrying the content of your node. you can use `print_r($content);` to see the list of the fields that you can use to your node (or if you use [Devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel), is best use `dsm($content);`)

**see this example:**

I have a field called `field_demotext1`, then this is the way that I can use to call their respective value inside any custom html zone of my node layout:

```
echo $content['field_demotext1']['#items'][0]['value'];
```

[image]

here is the example of zone in the `node--article.tpl.php` where you can use a custom html:

```
  <div class="content clearfix"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
    <?php
      // We hide the comments and links now so that we can render them later.
      hide($content['comments']);
      hide($content['links']);
      //print render($content); comment to hide all content
      echo $content['field_demotext1']['#items'][0]['value']; //will only show field_demotext1 value
    ?>
  </div>
```