# Getting fields of a content type in template file - creating a slideshow

Tags: 7, entities, database, theming

I need to add a slideshow *(each slide containing headline, image & html text)* in my frontpage. I've decided to create a custom `content type` named *slideshow* which should have above *fields*.

I've figured out the necessary `.tpl.php` file (*page--front.tpl.php*) in which I'll add codes to go for the slideshow.

### What I've done already

- Created a custom `content type` named *slideshow* with all the appropriate `fields`
- Added all the necessary html for the slideshow in the `.tpl.php` template file - with necessary javascripts already included using the `.info` file of my theme.

### Now the problem:

- I think I'll fetch data from database & populate the variables needed in `.tpl.php` file in: `preprocess` function of `template.php` file of the theme. **How do I retrieve the `fields` of *slideshow* `content type` from database?**

Please help!

Comment: BTW I'm using Drupal 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand well your question, I guess that node.tpl.php is more suitable for use templates per content types an control over individual fields:

[page.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--page.tpl.php/7): Default theme implementation to display a single Drupal page.

[node.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.tpl.php/7): Default theme implementation to display a node.

About **how to name your templates** according your needs, see this documentation: Drupal 7 Template Suggestions http://drupal.org/node/1089656. Regarding your case, I guess, a template for content type, the name could be `node--slideshow.tpl.php`. see [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/13280/display-content-type-in-custom-display-format/13282#13282) that have information related with node.tpl.php.

and about how to see your fields, the same link to [the answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/13280/display-content-type-in-custom-display-format/13282#13282) have one example:

I have a field called `field_demotext1`, then this is the way that I can use to call their respective value inside any custom html zone of a node layout:

```
print $content['field_demotext1']['#items'][0]['value'];
```

whit `print_r($content);` (or `dsm($content);` if you use [Devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel)) you will see fields that can be pulled. this screenshot is using `dsm($content);` related with the example;

[image: dsm $content]

[Render](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/render/7) Drupal API is an alternative to the previous way. In this way you does not need seek the file using `dsm()` or `print_r()`

```
print render($content['field_demotext1']);
```

Also, seems that [field_view_field](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.module/function/field_view_field/7) is another alternative to render Drupal fields. see [this](http://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/rendering-drupal-7-fields-right-way) related document:

I hope information be useful.

Comment: Thanks @MoonWatcher for taking time to answer elaborately... I'll check it out & notify you soon.

Comment: Is there a particular reason for advocating directly poking around $content instead of leveraging render() ?

Comment: Hi @MPD, no, I do not use `render()`, I am not familiar with `render()` (I am not familiar with lots of common functions of Drupal). `render($content['FIELD_NAME']);` works for show a particular field, your suggestion is very useful. I will update the answer with your suggestion. Also `field_view_field()` seems another useful alternative.

Comment: @moon.watcher I used it & it works perfectly _(I used `view` template files though)_ but unfortunately I'm getting formatted data which is undesirable for my purpose (breaks slideshow mark-up). Thanks for helping out... will you mind checking my new question? 

http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/13579/3235 - thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

### First solution :

Use the function "db_select" and make a SQL query

### Second solution :

Utiliser the function "node_load" but it will get the node you want.

Comment: That means, I need to (study and) work with DB API? :(

Hope there would be some easy-to-use functions already defined for retrieving `fields` of `content types`.

Comment: I'm thinking of making DB API calling. +1 for suggesting :)